# To color the image using flood fill algorithm in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

Am trying to color the specific portion of the image but the color applied for full image.. can anyone help me?

http://jsfiddle.net/hsbQH/10/

Comment: your CSS and JS files forbid hotlinking and are not loading in jsfiddle. PLease fix that first

Comment: You should use "Add resources" option on the left hand side to add external JS and CSS resources  to your fiddle

Comment: Fyi, it's better to use `[]` instead of `new Array()`. Besides that, you are using jQuery - so why do you still use `document.getElementById()` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider the structure of your code I got lost when I search for the initialization part (function names etc..).
Also, I'm not sure if you do this in your own code, but you cannot get image data using an image that is not in your domain for security reasons.

Just draw a small rectangle and try to fill it, if it is not working, update your jsfiddle and ask here again

Comment: In canvas tag click event is not trigger in some places. Is there is a solution to solve this problem.

Comment: Is your canvas always on top ? Maybe it is hidden by another one if you use layers with zindex